# Creating a picture book from a bunch of external images without text/margin

Tags: graphics

I have a folder of jpg files and want to create a PDF where at each page you show one picture in "fullscreen", so no margin or border. Just the picture, nothing else.

Is there a simple LaTeX code to archive that?

Comment: Are the pictures all the same size?

Comment: Seems like you can just use some bulk conversion software (like [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)) to convert all the image formats to PDF, then stitch them all together into a single PDF via the [PDF Toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Comment: @Werner Yes, they are all the same size. Thanks for asking. Each one 3024x4032 pixels. I want the paper format to exactly fit that ratio.

Comment: @Werner Is there no way to do it without having to convert them first?

Comment: You can do this in LaTeX, for sure. Are they all the same format (JPG)? Do the filenames have a consistent naming scheme (like `picture_01.jpg`, `picture_02.jpg`, ... or similar)?

Comment: @Werner Unfortunately, they have not (the filename is the timestamp the picture was taken at) but it's okay for me to add one line for each picture with the corresponding file name (this can be done by some self written script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following template to create a document consisting of an equally-sized image per page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}% For page geometry/layout specification
\usepackage{etoolbox}% For list processing/management
\usepackage{eso-pic}% For exact placement of content in the foreground/background
\usepackage{graphicx}% For inclusion of external images

% Change page geometry to match image size
\geometry{
  papersize = {3042px, 4032px},% width x height
  margin = 1in % Not really needed
}

\pagestyle{empty}% Remove any header/footer

\begin{document}

% How each image should be handled
\renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
  \clearpage% Move to next page
  \mbox{}% Set something invisible on the page
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{% Add image to this current pages's ForeGround
    \AtPageLowerLeft{% Position at lower left of page
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}% Make image fit the page
    }%
  }%
}

% Process image list
\docsvlist{%
  example-image-a,
  example-image-b,
  example-image-c%
  % ...more images
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your great answer. Now I have a little follow-up question. Maybe I should start a new thread for this? The question is: Now I want to have two images next to each other on the same page. How is that possible? So since my resolution of the images is 3042x4032 the new page resolution would now be 6084x4032.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: Would this be in the same document? So a number of 3042 x 4032 pages, followed by a 6084 x 4032 page or two (say)...